# Is there a standard name/notation for this partial order over subsets of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, order-theory

Let consider $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ and let us denote with $x_1, \dots, x_n, y$ the usual coordinates on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. We will also use the notation $x = (x_1, \dots, x_n)$. Moreover let us denote by $L_x$ the "vertical" line passing through $(x_1, \dots, x_n, 0)$, i.e.
$$
L_x := \{(x_1, \dots, x_n, t) : t \in \mathbb{R}\}.
$$

Let us consider the following partial order $\lhd $ over the power set $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^{n+1})$.

For $A, B \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$:
$$
A \lhd B \qquad \text{iff} \qquad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n: (L_x \cap A \ne \emptyset \, \,\wedge \,\, L_x \cap B\ne \emptyset) \rightarrow (L_x\cap A \le L_x \cap B)
$$
where "$L_x\cap A \le L_x \cap B$" is to be meant in the sense of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.

So in other words, $A \lhd B$ iff $B$ lies "above" $A$.

Is there a standard name and/or notation for $\lhd$?

Comment: What do you mean by "in the sense of intervals of $\mathbb{R}$"?

Comment: Good point! I edited! If $A, B \subset \mathbb{R}$, with $A \le B$ I mean that $a \le b $ for any $a \in A$ and any $b \in B$.

Comment: @bof Thanks a lot! Very nice counterexample. If you write your comment as an answer I will be happy to accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That relation is not a partial order. Consider the following subsets of $\mathbb R^2$:
$$A=\{(1,0),(3,1)\}$$
$$B=\{(1,1),(2,0)\}$$
$$C=\{(2,1),(3,0)\}$$
Then $A\lhd B\lhd C\lhd A$ and $A\not\lhd C,$ so the relation $\lhd$ is not transitive.